# Angualrjs - `$watch` not working for `this` declared controller object change

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am trying to `$watch` an object from controller. But it's not working. here is my controller code :

```
angular.module('myapp',[]).controller('myController', function(){

var vm = this;

vm.name = "myname"

})
```

In `directive`:

```
    angular.module('myapp',[]).directive('myDirective',function(){
    return{
    link:function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.$watch('vm.name', function(nv,ov){
         console.log(nv) //not working
    }
    }
    }
})
```

what is missing here? any one help me?

if I am not correct, help me to correct me here

[Live URL](http://plnkr.co/edit/xTH8ALQARvYOW9ZJNYfc?p=preview)

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: You don't appear to have specified which controller to use for your directive. Make sure you add the controllerAs

Comment: @phuzi - i am not clear, can you please detail me as answer?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify which controller to use in your directive

```
angular.module('myapp',[]).directive('myDirective',function(){
    return {
        controller: myController,
        controllerAs: 'vm', // this will let you use vm.name in any bindings
        link:function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.$watch('vm.name', function(nv,ov){
                console.log(nv) //not working
            }
        }
    };
})

function myController(){

    var vm = this;

    vm.name = "myname"
});
```

***EDIT***

Given your Plunker this solution wouldn't work for what you need

Check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xnhTD8SQ6nLSc9Edzx8j?p=preview) instead

Comment: Have updated [here (plunker)](http://plnkr.co/edit/xnhTD8SQ6nLSc9Edzx8j?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my code like this: it works for me

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.name = "no name";

  vm.update = function(){

    vm.name = "new Name";

  }

});

app.directive('myDirective', function(){

  return{

    link: function(scope, element, attrs){

     scope.$watch('Ctrl.name', function(nV, oV){

       console.log( nV );

     })

    }

  }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

"vm.*" will work when both the Controller and the View follow the same "controller as". You are using the same scope of controller inside the directive. You need to $watch using the Controller as alias.

```
ng-controller="MainCtrl as Ctrl"
```

```
scope.$watch('Ctrl.name', function(nV, oV){
    console.log( nV );
})
```

See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O2ARHKKaqJWgdOcgFb96?p=preview).

Ben Nadel has written a nice [**article**](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2852-understanding-how-to-use-scope-watch-with-controller-as-in-angularjs.htm) on this.